# Java for loop is not removing all empty arraylist lines

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I created new `ArrayList` of packages and with `loop` want to check, which packages have plans and which is don't have (empty). In my case I have 3 packages and all of them don't have plans (plans is all empty). If package don't have plan, I want to remove it. I tried to to in this way, but code removing only 2 of 3 packages. Don't know why, because all of them don't have plans.

```
List<Package> package = new ArrayList<Package>();
package.addAll(package3);

for (int i = 0; i < package.size(); i++) { 
    if(package.get(i).getPlan().isEmpty()) {
        package.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you delete an element, the indices shift.

Comment: If you delete from the list by index, you should decrement the index after delete.  However, it's much better and simpler to use `List::removeIf` as @Vulwsztyn suggested in their answer.

Comment: Alternative to incrementing indices and if you can't use `removeIf()` (which I'd prefer): use an iterator, i.e. `for (Iterator itr = package.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) { Package p = itr.next(); if( p.getPlan().isEmpty()) { itr.remove(); } }` (this is basically what `removeIf()` is doing internally).

Comment: @user16320675 sure you're right, I forgot to include the generics (or assumed the OP would add them when the IDE/compiler would warn about the raw type).

Comment: I would be surprised if that code actually compiles: `package` is a keyword and cannot be used as a variable name – unless some recent JLS version lifted that restriction.

Answer (score 3):

You could to it like this
`list.removeIf(s -> s.getPlan().isEmpty())`